# First Course in Linear algebra material request

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking for good materials (can be on-line pdfs or books) in Linear Algebra,specifically in the part of basis, coordinates of vectors and the relationship of them and the matrix representation of linear transformations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* by Treil. A pdf can be found on the author's website https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong .